# Função remover inicio Lista

Tags: c

Pessoal estou com essa função de remover no inicio, acontece que quando insiro números como por exemplo: 1 2 3, e depois chamo a função de remover no inicio e exclui o número 2, enquanto o correto era para exclui o número 1, porque é o inicio da lista. Já tente de tudo aqui, até meu limite e não consegui.

```
int retira_no_inicio (tipo_lista *p)
{
tipo_lista * aux;
//tipo_lista * ant;

if (p -> prox == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}

aux = p -> prox;
p -> prox = aux -> prox;
return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginemos que a lista é composta pelos três valores: 1, 2 e 3. O ponteiro `p` aponta para o início da lista:

```
+---+    +---+    +---+
| 1 | -> | 2 | -> | 3 |
+---+    +---+    +---+
  ^
  p
```

É verificado se `p->prox` é `NULL`, falso, portanto, o ponteiro `aux` receberá `p->prox`:

```
+---+    +---+    +---+
| 1 | -> | 2 | -> | 3 |
+---+    +---+    +---+
  ^        ^
  p       aux
```

E `p->prox` recebe `aux->prox`:

```
       +-------+ 
+---+  | +---+ |  +---+
| 1 | -+ | 2 | +> | 3 |
+---+    +---+    +---+
  ^        ^
  p       aux
```

Retornando `p`. Portanto, a lista final é:

```
+---+    +---+
| 1 | -> | 3 |
+---+    +---+
  ^
  p
```

Para corrigir, basta retornar a referência de `aux`, pois a lista passará a iniciar-se em 2, eliminando o valor 1. É bom lembrar que como está utilizando alocação dinânica ([fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200452/lista-ligada-ajuda-main)), você precisa liberar a memória do nó removido:

```
tipo_lista* retira_no_inicio(tipo_lista *p)
{
    tipo_lista *aux = p->prox;

    free(p);

    return aux;
}
```

> **Nota**: perceba que o retorno da função DEVE ser do tipo `tipo_lista` e não `int`.

Comment: De acordo com as últimas perguntas que você fez aqui na comunidade, que são TODAS referentes ao mesmo problema, recomendo fortemente você voltar ao básico e estudar os conceitos novamente. Se foi realmente você que fez estes códigos, não deveria ter tantas dificuldades em elaborar essas funções. Pegue seus livros novamente e reveja seus códigos. Será muito mais proveitoso para você.

Comment: Realmente não são códigos meus, estou estudando isso na faculdade e não tenho nenhuma experiência, estou no inicio do semestre, estou tendo um tempo livre e quero testar para ver se está certas essas funções que foram passadas, algumas eu consegui testar e outras peço ajuda no Fórum, só peço ajuda depois de tentar várias vezes. Mas muito grato pela dica.

Comment: Se tens tempo livre, esqueça os códigos prontos e tente fazê-los por si só.

Comment: Eu tenho muito dificuldade em programar, mas essa explicação sua ai foi excelente viu, poxa estou fazendo teste de mesa e entendi certinho.

Comment: Eu fiz uma função retira_no_fim com tipo int e deu certo.